# How to handle "click" event even if element is moved from beneath the cursor between mousedown and mouseup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an `<input>` and a `<button>`.

The input has an `onblur` event handler that (sometimes) results in the `<button>` being moved; if, with focus on the `<input>`, the user goes to click on the `<button>` (and it is thereby moved from beneath the pointer before the click completes) they must currently move their pointer to the button's new location and click it a second time.  This experience is suboptimal.

I would like for users to have to click the `<button>` only once (but must retain the functionality of the button moving when the `<input>` loses focus).  However, if a user mousedowns over the button and then *moves their mouse pointer away* (includes switching focus from the application) before mouseup, no click event should be triggered (as normal).

I can't see any approach based on handling `onmousedown` and/or `onmouseup` that would not be prone to errors in some edge cases.  All that I can think is to forcibly move the cursor in the `onblur` handler so that the click completes (if indeed it would?)—but this is probably a poor user experience too.

How can this best be handled?

```js
$('button').click(
  $('<li><input></li>')
    .children('input')
      .blur(function(){
        if (!this.value.length)
          this.parentElement.remove();
      })
      .end(),

  function(e){
    e.data.clone(true)
      .appendTo($(this).data('target'))
      .children('input')
        .focus();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
List 1<button data-target="#list1">+</button><ul id="list1"></ul>
List 2<button data-target="#list2">+</button><ul id="list2"></ul>
```

Comment: How about clone first and set opacity to 0 for original object. Then, make it go away on click or blur...

Comment: @RubyRacer: Awkward to keep the original object's position in place, when it is the document flow that has changed.  Any thoughts?

Comment: None of my thoughts shout "elegance" for this. How about a hovering (modal or not) clone, on mouseeover which will be fixed no matter what happens underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to fade the element out over the course of, say, a second rather than immediately, which gives the user time to complete the click before the button moves:

```
$(this.parentElement).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Live example:**

```js
$('button').click(
  $('<li><input></li>')
    .children('input')
      .blur(function(){
        if (!this.value.length)
          $(this.parentElement).fadeOut("slow", function() {
              $(this).remove();
          });
      })
      .end(),

  function(e){
    e.data.clone(true)
      .appendTo($(this).data('target'))
      .children('input')
        .focus();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
List 1<button data-target="#list1">+</button><ul id="list1"></ul>
List 2<button data-target="#list2">+</button><ul id="list2"></ul>
```

That said, I think I'd try to find a way that the space between the list elements didn't change at all, because this still means things move around, just at a different time — *hopefully* at a time the user will be less bothered by it, but... Tricky in this case, though, because of the lists being on top of each other — the second list is going to move at some point. If you made it that there was always an input box for the user to type in, then the second list would just move at a different time (when the box *does* have a value in it and you add a new blank one for the next value). Could be done with a fixed list size and scrolling within, but it depends on the overall design.

Comment: Thank you for these thoughts.  I hadn't considered having each list scroll, but in reality there are only going to be a small number of items in each list—so the fixed size would either be too small for scrolling to be a good UX, or so large that it wastes a lot of  space.  The "correct" solution is probably to provide a delete button per input instead of removing empty inputs automatically, but we want to avoid that if at all possible.  I think fading out may be an acceptable compromise and am inclined to accept this answer—but I'll leave it open for a bit in case other ideas emerge.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue where I was styling buttons to shrink on being pressed, using the `:active` pseudo-class to resize the button on mouse-down and resetting its size when the button gained focus with the `:focus` pseudo-class. However, if the button was clicked close enough to its edge, it still was activated and shrank, but the cursor was now just outside of the bounds of the button and the button would no longer gain focus.

This is a result of how the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event itself works. For the `onclick` event to be fired on a given `element`, the cursor must be "both pressed and released while the [cursor] is located inside the element." However, if the cursor moves outside of the element before being released, the event is instead fired on the "most specific ancestor element" containing both elements. In specific, this results in a `mousedown` event being fired on the `element` and a `mouseup` event being fired on its `ancestor element`.

A solution, then, is to monitor a button's `mousedown` event, and click the button if its parent's `mouseup` event is fired (i.e., the cursor was pressed over a button but released over its parent).

Vanilla JS code:

```js
// The CSS selector for the buttons to monitor
const selectors = "button";

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(selectors).forEach(button => {
        // Watch for button press
        button.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
            // The button is the event's original target
            const element = event.target;
    
            // Click if the cursor is released over the button's parent
            element.parentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                element.click();
            }, { once: true });
        });
    });
});
```

This works best if the button's parent is sized the same as the button (such as with `width: fit-content`). Otherwise, unintentional clicks can occur if the cursor is released far away from the button, but still on the button's parent element.